# Angular 5 Pass data from table in one component to another

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, angular5

I've seen a couple of threads discussing this but Im still confused over what is the right approach for my situation so Ill give this a try.

Background. I have a .net mvc app that Ive added angular 5 to and now Im, bit for bit, replacing Jquery scripts with angular components instead.

So, I have a list component that lists customers and on this list you have customer information and a checkbox. If you click on any of the checkboxes on this list, there is a button on the menu bar called `"move customer"` that goes from `'disabled'` to being able to push.

If you push this button a view pops up with a `'li'` that contains the name of the customer whose checkbox you checked. Also a hidden element of the customers Id is on the `'tr'` in this `'li'`.

What I want is to repeat this in angular. So, Listen for clicks on checkbox, un-disable the move-btn and send the data to the other component. AND there might be several customers that are checked so this has to be a continous thing, maybe a list or a subscription that keeps sending the data and filling a receiver list. Then it should list the name and id on the other component.

** **UPDATE** **

This is what I currently have:

This is my Service for sending data from list component to relocate popover component:

```js
import { Injectable, EventEmitter  } from '@angular/core';
import { EmployeeDataAttributeComponent } from './components/employee/employee.data.attribute.component';

@Injectable()
export class TableRowDataService {

    employeeDataAttribute = new EventEmitter<EmployeeDataAttributeComponent>();

    send(empDataObj: EmployeeDataAttributeComponent) {
        this.employeeDataAttribute.emit(empDataObj);
    }
}
```

My list component:

The `'tr class="gridrow"'` is what gets the class `'.selected'` when you check the checkbox. The `'tr'` also has the data I want as data attributes called `'attr.data-employment-name'` and `'attr.data-employment-personkey'` and I want these two for every checked or `'selected'` `'tr'`.

```html
<div>    
    <table class="employment-list new-style" *ngIf="filteredEmployees && filteredEmployees.length"
           attr.data-employment-organisation-nr="{{ filteredEmployees && filteredEmployees[0]?.EmploymentReference.OrganizationRegistrationNumber.FullValue }}">
        <thead>
          .....
        </thead>
        <tbody>
    <tr class="gridrow" 
        id="ngCheckRow" 
        #ngCheckRow 
        *ngFor="let employee of filteredEmployees" 
        attr.data-employment-name="{{employee.Name }}" 
        attr.data-employment-personkey="{{employee.PersonKey.CountryCode}}_{{employee.PersonKey._displayValue }}" 
        attr.data-employment-unitId="{{ unitId }}">
                <td><input type="checkbox"            
                    (change)="getdataAttributes({{employee.Name }}, {{employee.PersonKey.CountryCode}}_{{employee.PersonKey._displayValue }})"></td>
                <td id="pKey">
                    {{employee.PersonKey._displayValue}}
                </td>
                <td>AND SO  ON....</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

```js
export class EmployeeListComponent {
    .....
    empDataAttrObj: EmployeeDataAttributeComponent;
    //EmployeeDataAttributeComponent only contains two string props, name andpersonkey
    
getdataAttributes(attrName: string, attrPersonKey: string) {

    this.empDataAttrObj.name = attrName;
    this.empDataAttrObj.personKey = attrPersonKey;

    this.tableRowDataService.send(this.empDataAttrObj);
   }
}
```

This is my relocate component (The view for the popover that will show every checked customer) and what I am thinking for now. In the `'relocateForm'` is where the jQuery is that used to do this.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ButtonClickService } from '../../button.click.service';
import { TableRowDataService } from '../../table.row.data.service';
import { EmployeeDataAttributeComponent } from '../employee/employee.data.attribute.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'relocate-employment-popover',
    templateUrl: './relocate.employments.popover.html'
})
export class RelocateEmploymentsPopoverComponent {
    .....
    empDataAttrList: EmployeeDataAttributeComponent[];
    isAlreadyInList: boolean;


    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private buttonClickService: ButtonClickService,
        private tableRowDataService: TableRowDataService) {
          ........
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.buttonClickService.showRelocatePopOver.subscribe((relocateCLick: boolean) => {
            this.showPopover = relocateCLick;
            if (this.showPopover) {
                this.clearSearch();
            }
        });
    }

    //Get the data
    eventEmitterSubscription = this.tableRowDataService.employeeDataAttribute.subscribe(
        (dataAttrObj: EmployeeDataAttributeComponent) => {
            this.updateList(dataAttrObj);
        });

    //Check if it already exists in list, if true remove, else add.
    updateList(dataAttrObj: EmployeeDataAttributeComponent) {
        this.isAlreadyInList = this.contains(this.empDataAttrList, dataAttrObj);

        if (this.isAlreadyInList) {
            this.empDataAttrList = this.empDataAttrList.filter(item => item !== dataAttrObj);
        } else {
            this.empDataAttrList.push(dataAttrObj);
        }
    }

    contains(arr: EmployeeDataAttributeComponent[], obj: EmployeeDataAttributeComponent) {
        const proxy = new Set(arr);
        return proxy.has(obj);
    }
    
.....

}
```

```html
............
                            <div class="input-column">
                                <ul class="selected-employments" *ngFor="let employee of empDataAttrList">
                                    <li>
                                        <span>{{ employee.name }}</span>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="EmploymentPersonKeys" value="{{ employee.personKey }}">
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <span class="field-validation-valid hint" attr.data-valmsg-for="EmploymentPersonKeys" attr.data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
....................
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like you have a few ewquirements, the first one being:

> Listen for clicks on checkbox

For this, use a standard input element (type="checkbox") and Angular's (change) action, for example:

```
<input type="checkbox"(change)="changeAction(id, $event.target.value)">
```

By passing the id of the clicked element to the component, you're able to add it to the list. You may also pass an $event object (DOM checkbox) and access its target.value property, which in your case, will be either true (checkbox selected) or false (unselected)

> un-disable the move-btn

Use Angular's [disabled' directive:

Again, create isDisabled(id) method in your component when you'll pass the id of the row.  In the method, you just check if it was selected before (see above point)

> send the data to the other component

I'm not sure what data you need to pass, if it's a list of selected elements then it's easy either with the @Input directive on the component or by using a service and sharing the data in that way.

It looks like you should use a service in this case. So, write a service and a property that contains your data. Then two methods (Setter and getter) that will be available from your components allowing your to share the data between them. You may also write EventEmitters and raise events in your service so the subscriber component gets notified of the changes, like this:

in your service, declare and create:

```
public eventEmitter = new EventEmitter<YourType>();
```

and then in the setter/ update method of your service, do:

```
this.eventEmitter.emit(this.dataObjectYouWantToPass);
```

now, the last thing you need to do is in your component (the one that needs to be modified of the changes), subscribe to the service's EventEmitter:

```
this.eventEmitterSubscription = this.service.eventEmitter.subscribe(
            () => {
                this.doSomethingWhenTheDataChanges();
            });
```

Comment: Hi, sry for late answer. "pass" maybe is the wrong word, I mean share. These are two different components and I want the component that contains the objects and table to share the selected tr's two data attributes to the other component.

Comment: Im not sure how change works, can it be more specific? what if you uncheck the checkbox?

Comment: also, the button is in itself another component that has to be notified of the checking/unchecking of the checkboxes..

Comment: made an edit to list component following your first tip. Also added code from listcomponent to show the function

Comment: I've edited my answer to include more details how you can use the (change) directive with checkboxes and how you may want to use services and eventEmitter to share data between components.

Comment: Okey, I'll check it out, thank you. Btw, I edited the list component html again. I added the ngmodel and change to the tr, but it was supposed to be on the checkbox...

Comment: So, first of all, thank you! I've created a service and modified the components. I edited my post, give it a look and tell me what you think. My (change) function is not have you've done, for example. The only thing I have left is to set the 'disabled' on my button component.